# How to communicate with a StackExchange member about something not specifically related to a question

Tags: discussion

I noticed that [Jagra](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15734/streaming-data-into-mathematica-from-a-serial-port) made a comment about a question that is about something I'm interested in too. So I made a comment in the same question area asking him about it.  But I assume we don't want to mix personal interest questions into answers.

Is there a way to direct a question to a member that doesn't show up as part of the answer/discussion to a question?

Answer (score 10):

With [sufficient "reputation"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges/chat-rooms) you can create a chat room.  You can then post a single comment inviting that user to your chat room.  The chat room will be public but out of the way of normal Question/Answer traffic.

---

There is no "private messaging system" provided, even for the moderators (outside of actions like suspensions).  This is a deliberate "limitation" of the StackExchange platform.  See the main Meta question regarding this:

[Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

Comment: But what if someone does not want to share information over a public channel (like revealing an email address)? As far as I know, there is no secure way to do this, as SE does not facilitate such private conversations between SE citizens. Am I wrong?

Comment: @István I think you are right and this is exactly why I have an email address in my profile.  When I started using SO, I found it annoying that I couldn't contact some people, so at least I wanted to make sure people can contact me.  Some choose to publish an "anonymised" email address that won't give away their real identity.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I didn't know about the chat room thing. Perhaps I'm wrong, but it seems a bit cumbersome. I suppose I'm wishing for a way to send an email to a user's inbox so only he or she would see it. Perhaps invoked by clicking on the users name at the end of a comment. Not for secrecy, but to keep the discussion trail uncluttered. I gather we can't do that.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I agree with Szabolcs. Users can *choose* to put an email address in their profile, if they wish, but they don't have to. Seems like a good way to empower the individual users.

Comment: @George I updated my answer with relevant information.